# How to select multiple html-elements by class and change their different values?

Tags: jquery

I am searching for the right syntax for the following problem:

I got some elements on the page with the same class="power", I want select them all and raise their value by 3. How do i achieve this in jquery?

my solution so far, sets the value of all elements to 4.

```
<div class="power">1</div>
<div class="power">2</div>
<div class="power">3</div>
<div class="power">4</div>



 <script>
    $('.power').html(foo($('.power').html()));
    function foo(bla){
        var output = parseInt(bla)+3;
        return output;
    }


</script>
```

output

```
4
4
4
4
```

what i want

```
4
5
6
7
```

I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.each()`.

```
$('.power').each(function(){
    var output = parseInt($(this).text())+3;
    $(this).html(output);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
$('.power').each(function() {
  $(this).html(foo($(this).html()));
});
```